# Using trig functions to draw a tick mark

Tags: trigonometry

Without getting long-winded about the extensive backstory, I'm working with a programming language for data viz but it doesn't support degree axes. So one must append things like axis tick marks manually, one at a time. The task seems simple enough, draw a tick mark denoting the 30 degree mark, pictured in red below:

[image]

My environment doesn't allow me to rotate things. I must append lines only, which means I will have to know the exact `(x,y)` coordinates for both points of that red line. We shall call them:
x1,x2,y1,y2. I don't know these. But I do know "hypotenuse" which is the radius, in my case: 300. Each tick is to be 6 units long. And it would appear that x1,x2,y1,y2 can be calculated from `sin()` and cos()` if I have the angle and hypotenuse. After realizing I forgot everything from middle school, I tracked down the formulas and attempted to map out the logic.

- x1: This should be equal to the value of "adjacent" given `sin(30)`
  and hypotenuse = 300
- x2: This should be equal to the value of "adjacent" given `sin(30)`
  and hypotenuse+6 or 306
- y1: This should be equal to the value of "opposite" given `sin(30)`
  and hypotenuse = 300
- y2: This should be equal to the value of "opposite" given `sin(30)`
  and hypotenuse = 306

Relevant javascript below (Math.sin() accepts radians by default, but my data is in degrees, hence the conversion):

```
graphGroup.append('line')
    .attr('y1', Math.sin((Math.PI / 180)*30)/300)
    .attr('y2', Math.sin((Math.PI / 180)*30)/306)
    .attr('x1', Math.cos((Math.PI / 180)*30)/300)
    .attr('x2', Math.cos((Math.PI / 180)*30)/306)
    .style('stroke','#000')
    .style('stroke-width','1px');
```

Unfortunately the line was nowhere to be seen. I've been looking at my steps up and down and can't understand why my result is not the red line I was imagining. I've done the easy tick at 0 degrees, so in theory the code is fine. It is likely my math that has fallen short.

### Question

Is the above approach accurate for finding the x and y coordinates of the tick mark? Open to simpler solutions as well.

Comment: $/300$ and $/306$ should be $*300$ and $*306$

Comment: Adding to Empty2's comment, I'd suggest putting the "radii" $300$ and $306$ in front of the trig functions: `300*Math.sin(...)`. This matches the mathematical notation $(x, y) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ for polar coordinates, and clarifies that the factors are not inside the trig function. Separately, a one-line function radians_to_degrees (or rad2deg, or...) might be in order.